# Explanation Interface in java

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract

I Recently started java programming and i have problem about Interface Topic.

why using from interface in java?

```
public interface MyInterface {
void method1();
}
```

Comment: google it you will find a lot of articles.Do some research on your own first

Comment: in all of sites explanation about how implementation but no explanation about why and when using from it